# ember-electron use fs in third party npm module

Tags: node.js, ember.js, electron, fs

I need a third party npm package in my ember-electron app, that requires access to the file system ([ngraph.offline.layout](https://github.com/anvaka/ngraph.offline.layout), which also has several dependencies.

It uses the following function:

```
function createLayout(graph, options) {


options = options || {};
  var iterations = typeof options.iterations === 'number' ? options.iterations : 500;
  var saveEach = typeof options.saveEach === 'number' ? options.saveEach : 5;
  var outDir = typeof options.outDir === 'string' ? options.outDir : './data';
  var is2d = options.is2d ? true : false;
  var coordinatesPerRecord = is2d ? 2 : 3;
  var intSize = 4;
  var layouter = is2d ? layout3d.get2dLayout : layout3d;
  var layout = layouter(graph);
  if (!fs.existsSync(outDir)) {
    mkdirp.sync(outDir);
  }
  var lastIteration = getLastIteration(outDir);

  return {
    run: run,
    lastIteration: getLastIteration
  };
```

In my ember controller I have imported it like that:

```
import createLayout from 'npm:ngraph.offline.layout';
```

and then

```
g=graphGenerator.wattsStrogatz(1000, 10, 0.50);
 var layout = createLayout(g);
 layout.run();
```

But I always get the following error :
[image]

However when I do another request to the filesystem directly in my controller my own function works fine:

```
import toDot from 'npm:ngraph.todot';
var fs = requireNode('fs');

var stream = fs.createWriteStream('graphDot.txt',{
    flags:'a'
});

toDot.write(g, function customWriter(line){
    stream.write(line + '\n');
});

stream.end();
```

What exactly is the difference?

As the module performs an offline layout of a graph, it should be executed on the "server" and I was wondering if this is the correct approach?

EDIT1:
the import and requireNode resides in the ember controller of the specific route

Comment: Did you import the `fs` module in your first code snippet? Also please be aware, that electron has an renderer and main thread. AFAIK: In your main thread you have your nodejs code, which accesses the file system, while in the renderer thread you have your ember code which cannot use the `fs` module. Where does your code reside?

Comment: Yes, it was imported in the npm module ngraph.offline.layout. I could it get to work now, with `createLayout=requireNode(ngraph.offline.layout);` As I did it with fs for my other direct request to the filesystem. However, is this the correct way? I though when I import the module with requireNode in ember-electron, this would run in the main thread. The final result (working) suggests that. Thanks